# Why React show me this warning?

Tags: reactjs

Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

Comment: The default value must be `null`, try changing it to a blank string `''`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.